# SQL Query taking between specific sysdate?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using `Oracle DB 10g`, I am trying to take data between 2 dates, in the database format of data is :

`10/4/2013 9:04:38 AM`

I try some sql queries but it gives error...

```
select * from test_table where test_execution_date between '9/2/2012' and '7/2/2013'

select * from test_table where test_execution_date between '9/2/2012 9:04:38 AM' and '7/2/2013 9:04:38 AM'
```

It gives always same `error : ORA-01843: not a valid month`

Comment: It might not be parsing that format properly. Try `2012-09-02`, `2013-07-02`, `2012-09-02 09:04:38`, and `2013-07-02 09:04:38` respectively and see if you still get the error

Comment: Or are you intending to say you're storing *datetimes* as *STRINGS* in your database?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert string to date

```
select * from test_table where test_execution_date between 
TO_DATE('9/2/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY') and TO_DATE('7/2/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using

```
TO_DATE(thedatevalue,'MM/DD/YYYY')
```